Springboot-3.1.6.. Getting KubernetesClientException: Operation: [list] for kind: [Service] with name: [null] in namespace: [namespace] failed
I am trying to upgrade my current springboot application from version 2.2.2.RELEASE to 3.1.6. Since my application is deployed in kubernetes cluster, i had to upgrade associated spring boot kubernetes jars.. Like mentioned below for starter-kubernetes
             <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

to
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8</artifactId>
    </dependency>

I was using feign client with netflix ribbon for kubernetes interpod communication in my earlier spring boot version. But it seems ribbon is deprecated in the latest versions which makes me use spring-cloud-loadbalancer.
Now after deploying the upgraded version of my application in kubernetes cluster, I started getting frequent hits in my service logs of which stack traces are mentioned below->
20:30:24.171 [boundedElastic-3] ERROR org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.core.DiscoveryClientServiceInstanceListSupplier - Exception occurred while retrieving instances for service TEST-SERVICE io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: GET at: https://10.96.0.1/api/v1/namespaces/testnamespace/endpoints?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3DTEST-SERVICE. Message: etcdserver: request timed out. Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=500, details=null, kind=Status, message=etcdserver: request timed out, metadata=ListMeta(_continue=null, remainingItemCount=null, resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=null, status=Failure, additionalProperties={}).
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.copyAsCause(KubernetesClientException.java:238) ~[kubernetes-client-api-6.2.0.jar!/:?]
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.waitForResult(OperationSupport.java:517) ~[kubernetes-client-6.2.0.jar!/:?]
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:404) ~[kubernetes-client-6.2.0.jar!/:?]
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:378) ~[kubernetes-client-6.2.0.jar!/:?]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: timeout
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.waitForResult(OperationSupport.java:514) ~[kubernetes-client-6.2.0.jar!/:?]
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:404) ~[kubernetes-client-6.2.0.jar!/:?]
... 81 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException(Http2Stream.kt:675) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:?]
Also i see this is happening only in 2 hours interval and works fine rest of the time. I tried to add the below fabric8-all kubernetes dependency thinking that i have missed some k8 dependency, but still didn't help.
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>

After some research, i found that since my application's earlier versions were using ribbon, client side load balancing was handled by ribbon itself. And in latest versions we are using spring-cloud-load-balancer, it relies on internal service discovery implementation(kubernetes-discovery in the classpath) to check the available services within the kubernetes cluster. Agreed, everything works fine except during the 2 hours interval, wherein the kubernetes api server 10.96.0.1 ( looks like kube-dns ip) gives error of Message:etcdserver time out. At this moment service discovery fails thereby causing interpod communications to fail.
How can I identify what is causing this timeout of kube-dns service at this specific interval?. Is there any possibility if i can use something like netflix ribbon in my latest versions which does not rely on kubernetes-discovery for interpod communications via feign-client.

spring-cloud-kubernetes contributor here: if you want help with this, create a minimal reproducible example and present it on the projects github page. Then I can reproduce it and find the root cause. thank you

@Eugene thanks for the response. Will surely try but cant guarantee as this is reproducible in our production environment and there are some challenges for me to setup a similar reproducible environment. Thanks.
